# When to use JSOM over REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom

Is there any specific scenario where I should use JSOM instead of REST while doing SharePoint development?

I want to know is there any limitations for SharePoint REST API when comparing to JSOM.

Comment: Check https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93269/csom-vs-jsom-vs-ssom-vs-rest and [this](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/a-comparison-of-jsom-and-rest/) and let me know if it answers your question or you need more information.

Comment: Also check this: https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-csom-vs.-rest-...-my-preference-and-why/ and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194326/rest-api-limitations-on-premise-and-workarounds for SharePoint REST API limitations.